# ios8 and iPhone 6 Plus Tab Bar Size

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xamarin.ios, xamarin, iphone-6-plus

I am bulding an iOS8 app and i have noticed that on the iPhone 6 Plus my TabBars and Navigation bars are bigger than the stock Apple apps. I cant seem to find any documentation for this. How do i tell my top and bottom bars to resize for the bigger iPhones?

The screenshot below shows Maps next to my app. (Amended to show clock app instead.) I am pretty sure the clock app uses a TabBar Controller and not a toolbar as suggested below.

[image]

Comment: The comparison you have posted isn't really fair as Maps doesn't use NavBars or TabBars. (That's a UISearchBar at the top, not sure what type of view at the bottom, but it's not a UITabBar). I've never heard of this behavior before and the bars don't look particularly oversized to me- could you post a pic comparing with a native app that uses a NavBar and TabBar, the Clock app maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a proper Launch Image for the higher (`@3x`) resolution for the iPhone 6+?  If you don't you're app is going to get scaled, which is probably why it looks bigger.  Run your app with the debugger on an iPhone 6 Plus and look at the value of `UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale`.  If it reports back "2.0", then you don't have a proper launch image for your app, the resolution is being scaled.  Once you have the proper launch image, `UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale` should report back as 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

As J2K said to you, your tab and navigation are ok. Apple Maps app uses searchbar at the top and toolbar at the bottom which are smaller. Don't waste time on this, ios will handle the size for this elements for you in all iphone sizes